# Add shadow to custom shape made with border in CSS

Tags: css, box-shadow

Ok, so in HTML I have one div tag with a before and after pseudo elements. This is my CSS:

```
.divClass{
    background: #41423D;
    height:30px;
}
.divClass:before{
    content: '';
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-width :15px 7px 15px 7px;
    border-color: transparent #41423D #41423D transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -14px; 
}
.divClass:after{
    content: '';
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-width :15px 7px 15px 7px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #41423D #41423D;
    border-style:solid;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -14px;
}
```

So, in design it becomes like this:

```
 ___ 
/   \
```

> Now all I need is a shadow on the before and after pseudo elements which are the 2 triangles on either side of the div. The pseudo elements have 0 width and height so using box-shadow is a little tricky.
>
> > I need the shadow along the triangle. So, what can I do?

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what is the purpose of this shape ? Will there be text in it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use unicode character : ▲ to make the triangles.

Apply a text shadow on it.

If the shape of the triangle is not what you want you can adjust it with `transform: rotate();` or `transform: skewX();` or **both**.

It's a bit tricky and not perfect but it can works :

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 70px;
  transform: skewX(29.5deg);
  color: red;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px gray;
}
```

```html
<span>▲</span>
```

There are some other possibilities, all describe on a CSS Tricks post, so check it if you want :

https://css-tricks.com/triangle-with-shadow/

If think you can check `filter: drop-shadow()` too. In case you do not need a support for all the browsers it may works for you...

**edit:**

According to the css tricks post, can't you do that ?

```css
.triangle-with-shadow {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 10px -17px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.triangle-with-shadow:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #999;
  transform: rotate(45deg); /* Prefixes... */
  top: 75px;
  left: 25px;
  box-shadow: -1px -1px 10px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-with-shadow"></div>
```

Another possibility if you just want the shape that you describe is to use the perspective :

```css
.shape {
  background: #41423D;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  transform-origin:50% 100%;
  transform:perspective(100px) rotateX(30deg);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px #41423D;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Comment: I dont think the triangle unicode will work for me as I have right angled triangles in my case. And i need the solution to work for both firefox and chrome so drop-shadow ain't good either

Comment: I need one more help please. Can I get the edges sort of curved (like border-radius maybe). If I could get a specific curve like a bezier one, that would be great.

Comment: Can you send me a draw of it ?